# Tell MockK which objects to use for injection

Tags: kotlin, mockk

Is there a way to tell MockK which object to use when injecting dependencies?

Here's a simplification of what I want to do.

```
interface InternalDependency {
  abstract funToMock()
}

class Target() {
  private val internalDependency: InternalDependency by inject()

  fun funToTest() {
    internalDependency.funToMock()
  }
}

class MyTest {
  // given
  val internalDependencyMock: InternalDependency = spyk()

  val target = Target()

  // when
  target.funToTest()  // I want my mock to be used by target

  // then
  // verify whatever
}
```

I want my mock to be used by target but instead MockK is creating its own for it.  In my code the injection is buried about 4 layers down but I think this behaves the same.

Is there a way to tell MockK to use a specific object, such as `internalDependencyMock`, to fulfill the inject in `target`?

Answer (score 1):

I think just using dependency injection is enough. Change `Target` like this.

```kotlin
class Target(
    private val internalDependency: InternalDependency
) {
    fun funToTest() {
        internalDependency.funToMock()
    }
}
```

then, you can provide your mock as `InternalDependency`.

```kotlin
class MyTest {
    // given
    val internalDependencyMock: InternalDependency = mockk()

    // provide internalDependencyMock as InternalDependency
    val target = Target(internalDependencyMock)
}
```

or you can use `Koin` in the unit test. you will need dependencies.

```
dependencies {
    // your koin version
    def koin_version = "3.5.0"

    // Koin test dependency
    testImplementation "io.insert-koin:koin-test:$koin_version"

    // if you use JUnit4, include this line
    testImplementation "io.insert-koin:koin-test-junit4:$koin_version"

    // if you use JUnit5, include this line
    testImplementation "io.insert-koin:koin-test-junit5:$koin_version"
}
```

To use Koin in the unit test, the test class should implement `KoinTest`

```kotlin
// implement KoinTest
class MyTest : KoinTest {
    // your test codes
}
```

Set the `MockProviderRule` for JUnit4 or `MockProviderExtension` for JUnit5. I'll use `MockProviderRule`.

```kotlin
class MyTest : KoinTest {

    // if you're using JUnit5, use MockProviderExtension
    @get:Rule
    val koinMockProviderRule = MockProviderRule.create { mockkClass(it) }

    // your test codes
}
```

Now you can provide mocks to koin for the injections with `declareMock`.

```kotlin
class MyTest : KoinTest {

    @get:Rule
    val koinMockProviderRule = MockProviderRule.create { mockkClass(it) }
    
    @Test
    fun `test koin mock`() {
        // start Koin to use it for DI
        startKoin {}

        // given
        // declared mock to be injected
        val internalDependencyMock: InternalDependency = declareMock()
        val target = Target()

        justRun { internalDependencyMock.funToMock() }

        // when
        target.funToTest()  // I want my mock to be used by target

        // then
        verify { internalDependencyMock.funToMock() }
    }
}
```

I still think using the constructor injection is better as you can still use Koin with it.

You'll have to edit all of test codes that use Koin, when you migrate to another DI library and you must Koin to just write simple tests.